# Questions about group representation of infinite dihedral group

Tags: representation-theory, dihedral-groups

I am learning group representation theory, and I have troubles understanding the applications of group representation. Could you please help me to give explain the following question?

My question is:$$
$$
For infinite dihedral group:
$$
D_∞ = <r,s|s^2=1,srs=r^{-1}> 
$$
Then define a map
$$
\phi^α (r) = \begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 1  \\
    -1       & α
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\phi^α (s) = \begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0  \\
    α       & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then the question need me to show that for what value of α,
$$\phi^α$$will

1. extend to a representation of D∞
2. $\phi^α decomposable$
3. $\phi^α reducible$
4. $\phi^α faithful$
5. $\phi^α "isomorphic "to" \phi^β $ if and only if α=β

My major problem is that I can not figure out how to show it is a homomorphism because be definition of homomorphism, $$\phi^α(rs)=\phi^α(r)\phi^α(s)$$ How can I know the matrix of $\phi(rs)$ based on the information?

Also I only have a clue for part 3, I only need to show the above to matrices have common eigenvectors.

Could anyone help me with the rest of questions?

Thank you in advance!

---

**New Edit**
I total get how to do part 1 now. Could anyone help me with the rest of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\psi:F_2\rightarrow GL(2)$ where $F_2$ is the free group generated by $r$ and $s$ defined by

$\psi(r)=\pmatrix{0&1\cr -1&\alpha}, \psi(s)=\pmatrix{1&0\cr \alpha&-1}$

It is enough to show that $\psi(s)^2=Id, \psi(s)\psi(r)\psi(s)=\psi(r)^{-1}$to deduce that $\psi$ induces a morphism $\phi^{\alpha}$ on $D_{\infty}$ with the desired properties.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your hint! I actually tried this method before. but it ends up with the relations hold for any value of α...which makes me a little bit unconfident about the answer.   Thank you again! And could you plz give me more hints for the rest of the question?

Comment: If the relations hold for any $\alpha$ the result is true.

Comment: Oh! Thank you! I suddenly remember homomorphism means preserve algebraic structure which means all I need to prove is that the map also have the structure of D∞...that was very stupid of me to ask such a question...thank you! Also, please if you have any enlightening thoughts about the rest of the question, please tell me. I will sincerely appreciate that!